# SSH to a node in private subnet. Any other way except having a bastion? (for windows especially)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I created a VPC with private and public subnets on AWS. After trying quite a few times, the only way I could SSH onto the private machine was via a node on the public subnet (and using ssh -A). Now, my doubt is: is there no other way of ssh-ing onto the private node? Isn't it public to the creators of the node?

I am unable to wrap my head around why even the people who created that node in the private subnet cannot log into it (unless, I can and I don't know yet)?

And if it's true that the only way to ssh into it is via the bastion node, then, how do I RDP onto a Windows machine on the private subnet? Is the only way to do it is have a windows machine on the public subnet and use that to RDP onto the private one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of a private subnet is to protect it from the outside world. But the cost of this protection is the restrictions required.

In order to access a node/instance on a private subnet, you must go through a node/instance on a public subnet. There's no way around that. Otherwise, it's not private, and hence, not protected.

To RDP to a Windows instance in a private subnet, you do not need a Windows instance in a public subnet. In fact, it may be easier to use a Linux instance in a public subnet:

1. Using the SSH client of your choice, establish an SSH connection with a Linux instance in a public subnet (your bastion).
2. Create a "tunnel" through your SSH connection to your private Windows instance.

For example, if your Windows instance has IP 10.0.0.4, then you can create an SSH tunnel that will tunnel localhost:13389 to 10.0.0.4:3389. Then, when you RDP to "localhost:13389", your SSH client will forward that connection to the bastion, which will in turn forward it to your Windows instance.

Comment: Oh hmm. So, for production systems, it's usual to have this private subnet pockets in your data center and have this bastion node to help you login to any of the private nodes?

Comment: I am confused. I should create a tunnel that routes traffic from my laptop (Mac) to this windows machine via that linux instance. Based on my understanding, what you suggested above was I ssh onto the public linux machine first (bastion). Then create a tunnel, and then come back to laptop and use RDP? Or use the client on the laptop itself to create the tunnel right?

Comment: I have read about both local and remote tunneling and I think it makes sense, but I am unable to process it for this situation. I am just using the mac terminal. Should I do ssh -L 13389:<ip of bastion>:3389 <ip of windows machine>?

Comment: From your mac, ssh to the Linux bastion creating the tunnel between your mac and the Linux bastion. The bastion will then forward the connection on to your Windows instance: `ssh -L 13389:10.0.0.4:3389`. I have omitted the main connection params needed to connect to your bastion. The -L param will setup the tunnel. I assume 10.0.0.4 is your Windows instance Private IP address.

Comment: Oh so i did this :( it timed out (i allowed ssh traffic on the windows instance, apart from listening on 3389). okay let me try again.

Comment: Make sure your VPC security groups allows 3389 incoming on your Windows instance and 3389 outgoing on your bastion.

Comment: Hmm. So, I connect to the <bastion node> using ssh -A. Now I create the tunnel by doing ssh -L 13389:10.0.0.4:3389. This stays like that. Now, what i actually want to do is RDP from my mac to that windows machine. But that still doesn't work coz I guess the Mac doesn't know about the tunnel, does it?

Comment: And yeah I updated the security group of bastion to allow outgoing traffic on the port and for windows instance to have incoming on 3389 (actually AWS did the latter for me by itself)

Comment: One ssh command. Just add the `-L <tunnel stuff>` to your `ssh` command when you connect to your bastion to get your prompt. Then in your RDP client software on your Mac, RDP to `localhost:13389`.

Comment: Hey! I think this worked! (I mean, the mac client still tells me I cannot connect to the instance) but at least the prompt came up when I tried localhost:13389 on the RDP client! I will try again otherwise get back to you!

Comment: Funny enough, now when I try RDP, it doesn't show up the prompt at all. he he. it just says try reconnecting or contact your administrator. :(